# Prevent Hibernate from loading lazy ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I reduced the problem to 3 entities in my model :

- Station.
- Locations (several per Station).
- Groups of location (several per Station).

The `Location` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "***")
public class Location {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "s_id")
   private Station s;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "g_id")
   private GroupOfLocations group;      

 }
```

And the class for `GroupOfLocation` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "***")
public class GroupOfLocation {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //I do not want the Station to be loaded
  @JoinColumn(name = "s_id")
  private Station s;

}
```

When I get a Location by ID:

1. Its Station is loaded
2. The Location's group is loaded
3. The Group's Station is loaded **BUT** I do not need it.

**Problem :**  The group contains the station but I do not want it to be loaded. I expected that `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` would prevent the Station from being fully loaded but it does not work.

I have searched on SO and sometimes, the problem comes from a class declared as `final` but there is no final class in this model.

Any idea?

This is how the entity id searched by ID:

```
public Location getById(Integer id) {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Location> query = cb.createQuery(Location.class);
  Root<Location> entity = query.from(Location.class);
  Predicate whereClause = cb.equal(entity.get(Location_.id), id);
  query.where(whereClause); 
  return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any JPQL or Criteria query is going to [override the default](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-stratgey/) fetch plan (the one you defined in the entity mapping).

The default query plan is only valid when loading the entity using find or getReference

```
entityManager.find(GroupOfLocation.class, 1L);
```

The default @ManyToOne fetch is EAGER but since you haven't issued a join fetch those will be extracted with some additional selects.

The **location.group.station** won't be fetched with an additional select but a Proxy will still be there.

If the **location.station** happens to match the **location.group.station** then Hibernate will use the already loaded location.station, since inside a Hibernate Session object equality matches instance equality too (meaning there can only be one object of an Entity type with a given entity identifier).

So in case both **location.group.station** and **location.station** reference the same entity, you will see an initialized Proxy, otherwise the proxy will remain uninitialized.

If the session is closed and the Proxy wasn't initialized you will get a Lazy exception when accessing it.

Comment: Very complete and interesting answer. I tried with/without `em.find()` and with equal/different Station ID (i.e. location.station.id != location.group.station.id). When the station.id are different, location.group.station is never loaded(it seems that the `FetchType` is respected in both cases.). I try to see if using em.find makes 2 different fetch plans. Do you know if there is a mean to tell hibernate to explicitly set null for the second station? (I convert the model in JSON and it makes the station to be duplicated.)

Comment: It's not possible to force null where an actual associated row exists in the database. I would load the entities and create an alternative DTO structure that's going to become your JSON model. This way you separate the JPA model from a JSON view model too. It's both cleaner and you can easily deal with circular dependencies even if you have to do a more work to accomplish this task.

Comment: so what is the actual answer...?

Answer (score 0):

But you didn't declare fetch = FetchType.LAZY on s & group property of locations.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I did not declare `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`on group property of locations because I need to fetch the group. But, I do not want to fetch the group's station.

Comment: Vlad just gave the answer.